# Close GitHub web-based editor

Tags: github, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I close the GitHub web-based editor?

The web-based editor is a useful tool and very simple to start. You just need to press `.` to open.

But if you want to close and go back to the repository page, is there a shortcut key or an option to click?

Until this moment I don't know how to do it and I need to close the browser tab and access the GitHub repository manually.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to click in the sidebar menu.

[image]